# How can I convert this number to an RGB formatted Color

Tags: java, colors

I am given the following number in a txt file: -14629765 and am told to convert it to a Color with JAVA.

Could I use .getRGB() to get it? And how could it be done?

Thanks

Comment: `-14629765` is hex `FF20C47B`, so it seems the value is an RGBA value, not an RGB value. --- Anyway, which `getRGB()` method are you referring to?

Comment: getRGB() method supposedly will return the RGB value representing the color in the sRGB ColorModel. I'm just trying to find the way to format this number to RGB.

Comment: If @Andreas is correct, the nearest RGB value for #FF20C47B would be rgb(255, 32, 196).

Comment: @stray Although it's called RGBA, it is stored as ARGB, so it is `A=100%, R=32, G=196, B=123`. See javadoc of the [`Color(int rgba, boolean hasalpha)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color-int-boolean-) constructor.

Comment: thanks  for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-14629765` is hex `FF20C47B`, which is an RGBA value, so use the [`Color(int rgba, boolean hasalpha)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color-int-boolean-) constructor.

```
int rgba = -14629765;
Color color = new Color(rgba, true);
System.out.println(color); // prints: java.awt.Color[r=32,g=196,b=123]
```

The color is called [Mountain Meadow](http://www.htmlcsscolor.com/hex/20C47B): [image: x]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
int code = -14629765;
Color color = new Color(code);
```

More information you can find here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int)

Comment: That ignores the alpha component of the input (value `FF`).

Comment: @Andreas, yes, you are right. Your answer is better.